# Adding a shapefile to a feature layer using arcgis js api

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have the following code and up until a couple of weeks ago (or possibly one or two months because I hadn't used it in some time) everything seemed to be working fine:

```
function generateFeatureCollection(fileName) {
    require(["esri/geometry/scaleUtils", "esri/request", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/_base/lang"], function (scaleUtils, request, dom, on, lang) {
        var portalUrl = "http://www.arcgis.com";
        app.map.setMapCursor("progress");
        document.body.style.cursor = 'progress';
        //resolving the fakepath issue in the file location url
        var name = fileName.split(".");
        name = name[0].replace("c:\\fakepath\\", "");

        var params = {
            'name': name,
            'targetSR': app.map.spatialReference,
            'maxRecordCount': 12500,
            'enforceInputFileSizeLimit': true,
            'enforceOutputJsonSizeLimit': true
        };

        var extent = scaleUtils.getExtentForScale(app.map, 40000);
        var resolution = extent.getWidth() / app.map.width;
        params.generalize = true;
        params.maxAllowableOffset = resolution;
        params.reducePrecision = true;
        params.numberOfDigitsAfterDecimal = 0;

        var myContent = {
            'filetype': 'shapefile',
            'publishParameters': JSON.stringify(params),
            'f': 'json',
            'callback.html': 'textarea'
        };

        var genRequest = request({
            url: portalUrl + '/sharing/rest/content/features/generate',
            content: myContent,
            form: dom.byId('uploadForm'),
            handleAs: 'json',
            load: lang.hitch(this, function (response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    return;
                }
                addShapefileToMap(response.featureCollection);
            }),
        });
        genRequest.then(
            function (response) {
                //console.log("Success: ", response.layers);
            }, function (error) {
                app.notifyError("Error on upload.");
                $('#IEFill').append("<b>Upload Error: "+error+"</b>");
            });
    });
}
```

However recently an error is being thrown in the last part of the code where the line is:

```
app.notifyError("Error on upload.");
```

The following error is being thrown and I have been through all my code and have no idea what I may be doing wrong especially since this process was working and no changes were made to the best of my knowledge.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at Object.b.fromJson (init.js:230)
at Object.json (init.js:187)
at s (init.js:192)
at c (init.js:76)
at d (init.js:76)
at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (init.js:77)
at init.js:195
at k (init.js:199)
at m (init.js:199)
at f.resolve (init.js:201)
```

Would anyone know why this error is being thrown and any possible solutions for it?

Comment: That code seems to be a modifed version of the JSAPI sample at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html.  That sample seems to work fine. Maybe try and see how your code is different from that?  
Also, do you have the problem in all browsers  or just in one/some?

Comment: I can only test in chrome as my website was created to recognize chrome only. And yeah it was taken from there however up until some time ago it was working fine. I believe that the issue may be related with the proxy however I am unable to determine where the issue is coming from

Comment: The code for the function you shared above seems to work fine when I try it within that sample. If you think the issue is proxy related, maybe (a) test without the proxy, (b) test the proxy in general and (c) look at the proxy response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was caused because of updates to the following browser versions:

Firefox 49 (Release Date: September 20, 2016)
Chrome 54 (Release Date: October 18, 2016)
Safari 10 (Release Date: September 20, 2016)
As a result esri released a number of patches to counter this, however not all arcgis software versions were covered.

A list of the bugs discovered as well as a list of all arcgis software versions for which patches were released, together with additional information about this issue can be found [here](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2016/09/20/announcement-errors-encountered-in-arcgis-for-server-and-portal-for-arcgis-web-apps-after-certain-browser-updates/).

Comment: @PolyGeo why delete? This is the reason why this is not working, as otherwise the code is correct. Any users who try the same code will not know why their process is not working without this information.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue, and it wasn't a browser update issue for me so I am leaving my fix in case someone else comes across this problem.

My application is using Angular 2, and for some reason the POST request wasn't being properly encoded as 'multipart/form-data'.

I copied and pasted the example upload-shapefile js code from developers.arcgis.com and ran that code, and when I went to the 'network' tab in dev tools, and inspected the "generate" call, the Request Headers section was nice and pretty, as a multipart/form-data request is.

Then when I tried it from my angular application (which was using the exact same setup), i looked at the 'generate' request in the network tab, and it was sending the request headers as url or paramters. but it definitely wasn't multipart/form-data.

To fix the issue I just created a new FormData object and attached the parameters manually. As such:

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append('filetype', 'shapefile');
form.append('f', 'json');
form.append('publishParameters', JSON.stringify(params));
form.append('file', myFile)
```

In comparison to your code snippet above, my variable above, 'form', is going to replace your variable 'myContent'.

Once I did this, the post request to arcgis' 'generate' endpoint worked just like in their example.